# please suggest a good framework for dynamic form based web application

Tags: java, web-applications, forms, dynamic

Hi all
I have trying to create a dynamic form based application submission system.
Here application forms are dynamically generated from a control panel where the user
can design the form and data-type. When end user submits the forms it gets persisted into database.

What technologies can I use to efficiently design such a web based system in java.

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is the most suitable solution for what you want. If you have swing or swt experience, you would be easily familiar with GWT.

Well , similar web site to what you want; http://glowday.com/editor